# Pass extra parameter with the react router definition

Tags: reactjs, react-router

We're creating routes in ReactJS i.e. like that:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
  <Route path="/foo" component={SomeComponent} />
</Route>
```

Is it possible to pass an extra parameter to the `SomeComponent` from the `Route` definition ? What I have to achieve is reuse the same component and discover this provided value in it:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
  <Route path="/foo" component={SomeComponent} params={key: 'foo'} />
  <Route path="/bar" component={SomeComponent} params={key: 'bar'} />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that.

Within `SomeComponent` access `params` through `this.props.route.params`.

you will get the params passed from the route.